# How to send automatic email (with a link of google form) to email address (received from another google form)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form (let's say form 1) which collects email address & other information from responses. Now i need a apps script which will help me to send automatic email (with a link of another google form (lets say form 2) to email address (received from the responses of google form 1) whenever there is a new response.

Example of the google sheet:

[image]

Advance thanks for your help

I tried below:

```
   // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
    var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

I am expecting:
I have a google form (let's say form 1) which collects email address & other information from responses. Now i need a apps script which will help me to send automatic email (with a link of another google form (lets say form 2) to email address (received from the responses of google form 1) whenever there is a new response.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");` only gets the range of `B2` and doesn't work dynamically to get the range of the last row from the responses of the spreadsheet.

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var responsesheet = sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'); //just change the sheet name to where your responses are saved
  var emailAddress = responsesheet.getRange(responsesheet.getLastRow() ,2, 1, 1).getValue(); 
  console.log(emailAddress); 
  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
  var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

And finally, you can set the function on an `On-Form Submit` trigger so whenever a new response was sent using the form, the script will trigger automatically to send the email. For the link of the second form you can include the url on the message body.